# How to fix the redirct url issue in social linked in integration with springmvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, spring-social

i am facing one issue in linkedIn social  integration with spring mvc based web application updated their social library to 1.0a Oauth to 2.0 Oauth in linked in developer network i mentioned Redirect url to http://localhost:8080/Myproject/signin/linkedin here once  i run the project linkedin login page is coming but after entering user name password on click of login page is redirected  once again to login page it is not going particular page of application.
this is my spring code

```
 public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {


            ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new SignInAdapter() {

                @Override
                public String signIn(String socialuserid, Connection<?> connection, Nativewebrequest request) {

                    final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = request.getNativeRequest(HttpServletRequest.class);
                    final HttpSession httpSession = httpServletRequest.getSession(false);
                    final User user = userService.getUserBySocialId(userService.getSocialUser(socialUserId).getUserId());
                    final SecurityUser securityUser;


                    if (httpSession != null) {
                        final String token = (String)httpSession.getAttribute("invitationToken");

                        if(token != null && !"".equals(token)) {
                            System.out.println("user service token ...");
                            final Invitation invitation = userService.consumeInvitation(token);

                            if(invitation != null)                     user.setMembers(userService.getInvitationMembers(invitation.getEmail(), invitation.getInviteType()));
                                user.setRole(invitation.getInviteType());
                                userService.removeInvitations(invitation.getEmail(), invitation.getInviteType());
                                userService.createUserMember(member);
                            }

                            httpSession.removeAttribute("invitationToken");
                        }
                    }

                    securityUser = new SecurityUser(user);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(securityUser, null, securityUser.getAuthorities()));

                    return null;
                }
            });
```

client id and client secret id is mentioned correctly
i am little bit strck with this please help me sort out this is issue